# Outlook 2016 - Can I add shared mailboxes from Multiple servers?

Tags: exchange, outlook-2016, shared-mailbox

Our parent company has many individual companies under their umbrella. Each have their own IT teams, Exchange server, and domains all run independently of each other.

We now have a user that needs to add 2 different shared mailboxes, one from Company A and one from Company B.   Is this possible to do?  And if so, how?

I am asking as one IT Team said it isn't possible.  However I thought it was.  Thanks

Comment: AFAIK it is possible, but you would need a user account in both domains. The user account should then be granted access to each of the shared mailboxes.

Comment: Do you mean that they need access to a shared mailbox in each domain, which is a special type of mailbox specifically for shared use amongst multiple people or do you mean they need access to a mailbox in each domain.

Comment: Yes, they need access to a shared mailbox in each domain, not a normal/regular mailbox

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

**Option 1:**

The user need two accounts (one which has a primary mailbox in the primary exchange environment. Then a 2nd account which has the needed rights on the shared mailbox).

**Option 2:**

If its a parent company you might wish to trust both active directory environments and then build something based on that construct.